# Navigation bar large title not indenting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, large-title

I have a large title navigation and the title is not being indented to be in line with the UIBarButton items.

How do I fix this?:

[image]

Any help would me much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but i think you can add space like "  Timers" if you not find any solution.

Comment: You need to add some more details about how everything is setup and what device you are running on because by default it all looks fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
let p = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
p.firstLineHeadIndent = 5
navController.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: p]
```